# There are multiple good constructors and Room will pick the no-arg constructor

Tags: java, android, kotlin, local-storage

I have only one constructor but I do not know why the compiler keep saying "There are multiple good constructors and Room will pick the no-arg constructor."

I'm using java and Kotlin at the same time as I'm migrating to Kotlin but not very familiar with it.

The embedded BluetoothInfo class is in Kotlin while the MarkerEntity class is in java.

**MarkerEntity.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "marker_table", indices = {@Index(value = "light_id", unique = true)})
public class MarkerEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "light_id")
    private int lightId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lat")
    private int x;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lng")
    private int y;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title = "Default LightMarker";
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description = "No Description";

    @Embedded
    private BluetoothInfo bluetoothInfo;

    public MarkerEntity(int lightId, int x, int y, String title, String description, BluetoothInfo bluetoothInfo) {
        this.lightId = lightId;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        if (title != null) this.title = title;
        if (description != null) this.description = description;
        if (bluetoothInfo != null) {
            this.bluetoothInfo = bluetoothInfo;
        } else {
            bluetoothInfo = new BluetoothInfo();
        }
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getLightId() {
        return lightId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public BluetoothInfo getBluetoothInfo() {
        return bluetoothInfo;
    }

    public void setLightId(int light_id) {
        this.lightId = light_id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setBluetoothInfo(BluetoothInfo bluetoothInfo) {
        this.bluetoothInfo = bluetoothInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return lightId + " " + x + " " + y + " " + title + " " + description + "\n" + bluetoothInfo.toString();
    }
}
```

**BluetoothInfo.kt**

```
data class BluetoothInfo

@JvmOverloads constructor(private val bluetoothName: String = INVALID_BT_STRING, private val bluetoothAddress: String = INVALID_BT_STRING,
                          private val bluetoothUuid: String = INVALID_BT_STRING, private val bluetoothMajor: String = INVALID_BT_STRING,
                          private val bluetoothMinor: String = INVALID_BT_STRING, private val rssi: Int = INVALID_RSSI,
                          private val distance: Float = INVALID_DIST) {

    companion object {
        const val INVALID_RSSI = 99
        const val INVALID_DIST = -1f
        const val INVALID_BT_STRING = "invalid"
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "name: $bluetoothName, addr: $bluetoothAddress, uuid: $bluetoothUuid \n" +
                "major: $bluetoothMajor, minorL $bluetoothMinor, rssi: $rssi" +
                "dist: $distance"
    }

}
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

I tried the Android Studio Kotlin converter for MarkerEntity.java but the error still persists.

**MarkerEntity.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = "marker_table", indices = [Index(value = ["light_id"], unique = true)])
class MarkerEntity(lightId: Int, x: Int, y: Int, title: String?, description: String?, bluetoothInfo: BluetoothInfo?) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id = 0
    @ColumnInfo(name = "light_id")
    var lightId: Int
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lat")
    var x: Int
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lng")
    var y: Int
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    var title = "Default LightMarker"
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description = "No Description"
    @Embedded
    var bluetoothInfo: BluetoothInfo? = null

    override fun toString(): String {
        return lightId.toString() + " " + x + " " + y + " " + title + " " + description + "\n" + bluetoothInfo.toString()
    }

    init {
        var bluetoothInfo = bluetoothInfo
        this.lightId = lightId
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        if (title != null) this.title = title
        if (description != null) this.description = description
        if (bluetoothInfo != null) {
            this.bluetoothInfo = bluetoothInfo
        } else {
            bluetoothInfo = BluetoothInfo()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post a stack trace

Comment: Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983393/there-are-multiple-good-constructors-and-room-will-pick-the-no-arg-constructor

Comment: Is it an error or warning?. Can you kindly post the stacktrace

Comment: Can't reproduce for now and kinda fixed the issue. It's an error btw.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow fixed the issue by rewriting BluetoothInfo.kt into java and putting @ColumnInfo before each variable.

**BluetoothInfo.java**

```
public class BluetoothInfo {

    private static final int INVALID_RSSI = 99;
    private static final float INVALID_DIST = -1f;
    private static final String INVALID_BT_STRING = "invalid";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "bluetooth_name")
    private String bluetoothName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bluetooth_addr")
    private String bluetoothAddress;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bluetooth_uuid")
    private String bluetoothUuid;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bluetooth_major")
    private String bluetoothMajor;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bluetooth_minor")
    private String bluetoothMinor;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rssi")
    private int rssi;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "distance")
    private float distance;

    public BluetoothInfo(String bluetoothName, String bluetoothAddress, String bluetoothUuid, String bluetoothMajor, String bluetoothMinor, int rssi, float distance){
        this.bluetoothName = bluetoothName;
        this.bluetoothAddress = bluetoothAddress;
        this.bluetoothUuid = bluetoothUuid;
        this.bluetoothMajor = bluetoothMajor;
        this.bluetoothMinor = bluetoothMinor;
        this.rssi = rssi;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getBluetoothName() {
        return bluetoothName;
    }

    public String getBluetoothAddress() {
        return bluetoothAddress;
    }

    public String getBluetoothUuid() {
        return bluetoothUuid;
    }

    public String getBluetoothMajor() {
        return bluetoothMajor;
    }

    public String getBluetoothMinor() {
        return bluetoothMinor;
    }

    public int getRssi() {
        return rssi;
    }

    public float getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setBluetoothName(String bluetoothName) {
        this.bluetoothName = bluetoothName;
    }

    public void setBluetoothAddress(String bluetoothAddress) {
        this.bluetoothAddress = bluetoothAddress;
    }

    public void setBluetoothUuid(String bluetoothUuid) {
        this.bluetoothUuid = bluetoothUuid;
    }

    public void setBluetoothMajor(String bluetoothMajor) {
        this.bluetoothMajor = bluetoothMajor;
    }

    public void setBluetoothMinor(String bluetoothMinor) {
        this.bluetoothMinor = bluetoothMinor;
    }

    public void setRssi(int rssi) {
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }

    public void setDistance(float distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```